# how to utf-8 decode a jsonfile in swift 3/4

Tags: json, swift, encoding

I have been trying for a long time to decode a json-file with danish letters in Xcode Swift 3 and 4. It works fine as long as it doesn't have to read danish letteers such as å,ø,å.
This is my code:

```
    let myFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "json")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: myFile!)
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
```

I can extract data from the file like this

```
let navn = JSON(json)["navn"].string!
```

But... If I the file contains something like

```
"navn":"Gentofte Sø"
```

The app crashes due to the "ø".
I know it should be utf8 decoded, but I can not seem to work out how to do it, as all the examples I have seen so far has been with data from an url, og dummy data in string-format.

Comment: Why are you using JSONSerialization *and* SwiftyJSON? It should be one or the other. Not only you're wasting process power but you risk having encoding errors. Also you should never force unwrap `.string`, it's an optional for a reason. When you *know* it can't fail there's `.stringValue` to get the non-optional result.

Comment: Is the JSON text file in the bundle properly UTF8 encoded? By the way, there is an API `Bundle.main.url(forResource:withExtension:)` that avoids the extra step to create the URL

Comment: I'm afraid we'll need an MCVE here -- the actual file, and the actual program.  Are you sure it's UTF-8?

Comment: Moritz: 
well... you got me, I am pretty new to IOS dev. didnt realize it had to be one or the other -  (yes I know about the force unwrap)

vadian and Sswift
usually it is UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 is an other option.I haven't explicitly set it to UTF-8 encoding -  but I would like to know HOW to set encoding of a file in swift in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I Have to say that I was working with firebase database, so, in this context I found the solution like this

```
  if let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json") {
        do {
                 let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: path, options: .mappedIfSafe)
            do {
                 let responseStrInmacOSRoman = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.macOSRoman)

                guard let modifiedDataInUTF8Format = responseStrInmacOSRoman?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16) else {
                    print("could not convert data to UTF-8 format")
                    return
                }


                if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: modifiedDataInUTF8Format, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? NSDictionary {
                    do {
                    if let gpsMapped = jsonResult.value(forKey: "gpsmapped") as? String {
                        ref?.child("myFirstChild").child(fileName).child("mySecondchild").setValue(gpsMapped)
                        alData += "," + gpsMapped
                        print(gpsMapped)
                    }
        }
            } catch {}

            }
        catch{}
        }
```